# RSA Coding Question

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I have been given that N=143 and the encoder E=7. An encrypted message 48 was received. I have to find the decoder and use it to compute the original message.

This is how I did it but i'm not sure if I did it right:
I let $M$ = the original message, then $$M^7 \equiv 48mod143$$ and we want some decoder $D$ such that $$48^D \equiv Mmod143$$ Then i  did $$7D = 1(mod(p-1)(q-1))$$ $$7D \equiv 1(mod143)$$ $$7(41) \equiv 1(mod43)$$ I found 41 by trial and error.
 Using this i found that $$48^41 \equiv 81(mod143)$$
Does this mean the original message is 81?

Comment: $\LaTeX$ hints:  for multicharacter exponents, enclose them in braces, so 48^{41} gives $48^{41}$, for modulus, use \pmod, so 81 \pmod {143} gives $81 \pmod {143}$

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you want $7D \equiv 1 \pmod {(p-1)(q-1)}$, but it is $pq=143$, so you want $7D \equiv 1 \pmod {120}$, not $\pmod {143}$

Comment: Ok, so then D would equal 103? And then i have to find the remainder when $48^{103}$ is divided by 102? Which equals 72, so is 72 the original message?

Comment: $D=103$ is correct, but you need to review how to use it.  You can check your decryption with your first equation $M^7 \equiv 48 \pmod {143}$  No, the message is not $72$

Comment: Sorry, i still can't figure out what is next.

Comment: You recover the message by raising the encrypted message to the decryption exponent, so $M=48^{103} \pmod {143}$

Comment: So then M would equal 9?

Comment: That is right.  Then $9^7 \equiv 48  \pmod {143} $ checks.

Comment: Thank you! Does this mean that the original message is 9? The RSA process itself confuses me.

Comment: That is right. If $M$ is the message, $E$ the encryption exponent, $D$ the decryption exponent, and $C$ the cybertext, we have $C=M^E,M=C^D \pmod {143}$  The process above is to find $D$ given $E$